# How to find out if Unicode works correctly on unix/linux CLI

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, unicode, command-line

Still some apps seem to have problems with unicode terminals/output. I am looking for a app (or script) which prints out some unicode formated text and line drawing (like ncurses). Thus help to figure out if the app is broken or the (terminal/env/ssh-client) settings are wrong. Which app does this and is most likely to be installed on a linux system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a text file with some Unicode characters and use that as your testcase.  You can then use `cat` or shell redirection to send the file's contents to another program to test whether it works.

If you want more details, give us a specific example you're considering.

Comment: unicode ncurses would be nice

Comment: `less unicode-testfile.txt` ... `lynx unicode-testfile.txt` ... `nano unicode-testfile.txt` ... all of these use `ncurses` to some extent.